# In netbeans 7 how do I skip testing and add maven additional parameters when building a maven project?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin, netbeans-7

I want to issue commands like `-Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dcheckstyle.skip`

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Go to your project properties. Right click on the project name in *Project Explorer* and click **Properties**. Select **Actions**.

Select the configuration that you are interested in. Select the action that you are interested in. Under set properties you can add the skip test and so on.

[image: Netbeans Property Window]

Answer (score 17):

You can also set up global commands by going to:

Tools->Options->Miscellaneous->Maven->Edit Global Custom Goal Definitions.

These will be available to all maven projects.

Comment: In NetBeans 7.3, that option has moved to: Tools->Options->Java->Maven->"Skip tests"

Comment: You da real MVP Enwired! Your hint made the job!

Answer (score 12):

In Netbeans 8.2 in addition to

```
Tools->Options->Java->Maven->Execution->Skip Tests (checkbox)
```

in the same dialog you may need to add `-Dmaven.test.skip` to the

```
Global Execution Options (textfield)
```

[image: Skip Tests]